# Prove that exponential series squared is continous

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, exponential-sum

Prove that $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^2, z \in \mathbb{C} $$ is well-defined and continous.

I'm aware of the Weierstrass M-test, but I failed to find a proper estimation to apply it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sum of the series is differentiable in the circle of convergence, provided the radius is $>0$ (including radius $\infty$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that the interval of convergence is all of ${\bf{C}}$. By ratio test, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{z^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right)^{2}}{\left(\dfrac{z^{k}}{k!}\right)^{2}}\right|&=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{|z|}{k+1}\right)^{2}=0,
\end{align*}
so interval of convergence is the whole $\{|z|<\infty\}$, so the series converges on the whole plane. And we know that it is continuous on each compact box, and hence continuous on the whole plane.

Comment: Another way would be, fix a $z\in{\bf{C}}$, and consider a compact box that containing $z$, then Weierstrass M-test should be working on that compact box.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why we know that it is continous on each compact box?

Comment: This is a standard fact about power series, essentially the proof is similar to what I have written, fix a $z$ and choose compact box for it, and then do Weierstrass, you may take any book of mathematical analysis, there is no much different between real or complex case.